# Can we apply $2$ different quantifiers to the same variable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So I'm very new to FOL and I've been trying to wrap my head around quantifiers and the scope of them however I got a bit confused on this example

$\forall x\in D [p(x) \implies \exists x d(x)]$

Does this mean verbally for all $x \in D$ if p(x) is true then there exsists an $x \in D$ such that property $d(x)$ is true since the $\forall x$ scopes everything in the implication then everything in the implication must be an element of $D$ .
however I  know that $2$ different quantifiers cannot quantify the same variable so is it just then for all $x \in D$ if $p(x)$ is true then there exsists some x possibly not in $D$ such that $d(x)$ is true?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different variables can have the same "name", for example $x$, but they're still two distinct variables.

Comment: Even if it is allowed in some systems, such overloading of variable names within a statement is never necessary. Logically equivalent and more readable would be: $~\forall x\in D [p(x) \implies \exists y ~d(y)]$.

Comment: You may also want to write $~\forall x\in D~ [p(x) \implies \exists y\in D ~d(y)]$.

Comment: @dan christensen isn't the 2nd incorrect though x need not be in D

Comment: @Thehomeschooler Not necessarily. The second $x$ quantifier is supposed to be for another variable.

Comment: $\forall x\in D~.(p(x)\to\exists y \in D  ~d(y))$ is not correct right according to Graham kemps answer y is no longer restricted to fall within D so saying y is in D is incorrect we just say that there exsists a y that satisfies $d(y)$ however y could be in D

Comment: @Thehomeschooler I'm just saying that, for clarity, you should probably restrict the existential quantifier to D or some other set as implicitly done in most math proofs. It looks weird to overload a quantified variable like this, and to restrict one quantifier and not another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantifiers $\forall x\in D~$ and $\exists x$ each bind all **free** occurrences of $x$ inside their scope. However, any such occurrence can be bound to only one quantifier, and its immediate container has precedence.

Since such occurrences of $x$ inside the scope of $\exists x$ are bound to that quantifier, therefore they are not considered free inside the scope of $\forall x\in D$.

$\forall x\in D~.(p(x)\to\exists x~d(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x\in D~.(p(x)\to\exists y~d(y))$ (with the caveat that $y$ does not occur free in $d(x)$ and is thus substitutable).

---

"For anything in $D$, should it satisfy $p(~)$ it will imply that *something*$^\dagger$ will satisfy $d(~)$."

$\dagger$ not necessarily the same thing, nor does it even need be in $D$.

Comment: so it was my 2nd idea of the definition that was the right one ?